# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{(x-3)(x-2)}dx$ using residue thoerem

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{(x-3)(x-2)}dx$ using the residue theorem. To do so, I am integrating the function $f(z)=\frac{ze^{i\pi z}}{(z-3)(z-2)}$ over a the frontier of $\{z:|z|<R,Im(z)>0\}-(\{z:|z-2|<r\}\cup\{z:|z-3|<r\})$ (a semicircle that "avoids" the singularities of $f$).

I have used Jordan's lemma to prove that the integral over the big semicircle is null when $R\longrightarrow \infty$. My problem is I do not know how to compute the integral over the small semicircles when $r\longrightarrow 0$. How could I approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think $M-L$ inequality would help you here.

Answer (score 1):

For a pole $z=\alpha_i$ lying on $X-$axis in the contour you described, the value of the integral:

> $\int_{C_{r_i}}f(z)dz=-\pi i\times Res[f(z), z=\alpha_i]$ where $C_{r_i}:|z-z_i|<r_i$ traced clockwise in upper half plane.

The negative sign accounts for the clockwise direction you trace on the $X-$axis and $\pi i$ rather than $2\pi i$ is due to semicircle.

**ADDED**- $f(z)$ has *simple pole* at $z=\alpha$. From Laurent's series

$f(z)=\frac{a_{-1}}{z-\alpha}+g(z)$

Integrate both sides and parametrize by circle $C_r:z-\alpha=re^{i\theta},0<\theta<\pi$ to get

$\int_{C_r}f(z)dz={a_{-1}}\int_0^\pi id\theta +\int_0^\pi g(\alpha+re^{i\theta})re^{i\theta}d\theta$

As the second integral goes to zero as $r\rightarrow 0$ using  ML-inequality

($\because |g(\alpha+re^{i\theta})|\le M\implies |I_2|\le \pi rM$)

$\int_{C_r}f(z)dz=\pi i\times Res[f(z), z=\alpha]$

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a *simple* pole for this to be guaranteed?

Comment: This should work for pole of any order.

Comment: Why is that true? It looks like you are applying some standard result, but I do not think I am familiar with that.

Comment: If it is a *simple* pole then if you go round an arc of angle $\alpha$ and radius $r$ you get $\alpha i\times \text{residue}$ as $r\to 0$. It is a standard result. [I don't think it's true in general though.]

Comment: Yes, now I realized that the pole must be simple to use this result. Thanks